# How to replace the PHP sorting to SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

Pseudocode

```
$res = Query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15");
SortArray(&$res, 'date', 'asc');
```

If describe in words, then take the last part of the data is sorted in descending order from the database, but to give the data sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you just want to sort 15 elements in ascending order, or do you want to get all data sorted in descending order, but sort the top 15 results in ascending order ?

Comment: Select last 15 entry in ascending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$res = Query("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15) ORDER BY `date` ASC");
```

Comment: The correct version: SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15) AS `res` ORDER BY `date` ASC

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function to sort the array by specific key:

```
$res_array=array();  
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res))  
   $res_array[]=$row;  

$new_arr = usort($res_array,"my_func");  
function my_func($a, $b)  
{  
    if ($a['date'] == $b['date']) {  
        return 0;  
    }  
    return ($a['date'] < $b['date']) ? -1 : 1;  
}
```

*may need some debugging. take the idea.

Comment: He's asking how to do the sorting in SQL rather than PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making some magical SQL query, you should select *15  first rows in descending order*. And then just read the results from the end.

```
$statement = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15');
if ( ! $statement->execute())
{
    throw new Exception('query failed !');
}

$data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ( $row = array_pop($data))
{
    var_dump( $row );
}
```

Comment: @Ticksy , you might notice, that in question there was no "existing code" included .. thus no context.

Comment: Your variant is possible, but rather refers to the sorting in PHP.